# Is there something wrong with my terminal(bash)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, command-line, command-line-arguments

Reopened VS Code after committing earlier to find this message

```
sed: illegal option -- r
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]
```

Did I do something to my terminal or is this like an update or something?

Thanks again.

Comment: you would have to find what is calling `sed`. Do you have the same message when you open `bash` (or `git-bash` if you are running Windows) ?

Answer (score 0):

maybe something is wrong in your PATH setting, hope this can help you to check the PATH:

```
sed --version
which -a sed
type -a sed
echo $PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

Some versions of `sed` have a `-r` option and some don't.  (It means "use extended regular expressions"—i.e., POSIX EREs—on those that do have it.)  Some program you're running is trying to invoke `sed -r`, and the `sed` you're getting when this program runs is one that lacks the `-r` option.

Your choices at this point include:

- stop running that program (whatever it is—it's not Git);
- find that program and fix it to not require `-r`;
- install a version of `sed` that handles `-r`.

Answer (score 0):

There seem the be a bug in VScode v1.71.0 which gives this error on MacOS machines.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/e55863c5c1fc4515bd99e9cd4fb415788000a8b1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after updating to August 2022 (version 1.71) on my Mac OS 10.13.6. I installed the previous release and then noticed a warning in the terminal

[image: screenshot of terminal with warning icon]

I hovered over the warning icon and then saw a message box:

> Extensions want to make the following changes to the terminal's
> environment:
>
> GIT_ASKPASS=/Applications/Visual Studio
> Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/git/dist/askpass.sh
> VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_NODE=/Applications/Visual Studio
> Code.app/Contents/Frameworks/Code Helper.app/Contents/MacOS/Code
> Helper VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_MAIN=/Applications/Visual Studio
> Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/git/dist/askpass-main.js

I clicked on the "Relaunch terminal" link, and the problem was resolved.

I tried updating once again but the warning didn't show up.

As mentioned by [Sabrina N](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73582022/15007434), it's a VSCode bug in the current release.

I haven't experienced any problems working with the current release and subscribed to the [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/e55863c5c1fc4515bd99e9cd4fb415788000a8b1) for updates.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).